# Chrome back/forward gestures no longer working after Mavericks update

Tags: google-chrome, macos

Has anyone else noticed their 1 finger back/forward gestures no longer working in Chrome?
I have tried the gestures on other applications such as Safari and Mission Control, they are all still intact.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Make sure you enable: System preferences > Mouse > Swipe between pages

**AND OPEN A NEW TAB** in Chrome

If you had it working before but then **it stopped working** suddenly (usually after an OS / Application update) you might just have to uncheck / recheck the "Swipe between pages" option. That should solve it.

Comment: I didn't even need to open a new tab.

Comment: works for me too!

Comment: i upgraded to el capitan to use magic trackpad 2, and it seems like the gesture changed from 'swipe with two fingers' to 'scroll with two fingers'. Make sure the gesture matches your expectations even after the Swipe between pages gesture is enabled.

Answer (score 23):

In System preferences > Trackpad > Swipe between pages (under more gestures tab)
Uncheck it and recheck it.

Should work in Chrome now. You may need to do it when first installing Chrome or updating Chrome.

Comment: UNCHECK / RECHECK. Perfect ✅

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you enable: **System preferences > Mouse > Swipe between pages**

Comment: It worked for me by doing: System preferences > Mouse > Swipe between pages Thanks, couldn't live without it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I disabled my chrome extension (crxMouse), and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've noticed that too. I already reported that error to Google via the Chrome's `Options panel -> tools -> report errors`.

Hopefully they'll fix it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Better Touch Tool installed?  If so, uninstall it as it doesn't play nice with Mavericks atm.  Also if you dont have it installed, I changed the tracking speed, as I had previously set it with Better Touch Tool.

I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report already on the Chrome forums. Check it out [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/FjjdquTVNBE) and add your info too.

It seems to be a sporadic problem; I have the issue every hour or so, but my colleague doesn't get it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mine stopped working too, but realised I had installed a chrome plugin called 'SmoothScroll' (or something similar).  Uninstalling this gave me my gestures back, Happy times!

Comment: Thanks Jac, SmothScroll is the culprit!! I disabled it on mine and got my swipe between pages back!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414103) which is fixed in the [64-bit Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) which I use. It's a beta but works fairly well, I haven't noticed any problems except the headbar occasionally not retracting in presentation mode.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a while back as well.  When I looked at my Chrome extensions, I had one enabled called Smooth Scroll.  When I disabled that extension, my gesture swipe returned to normal.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this annoying bug.

The magic mouse right swipe for "back" doesn't work most of the time, but does after swiping with the trackpad once.

Chrome 60
macOs 10.13 public beta 5

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue before chrome update, after the update `Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` issue is resolved.